# ExtJS setTitle() doesn't update the panel title

Tags: model-view-controller, panel, title, extjs4.2

I have a panel as follows:

```
Ext.define('TestPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.testPanel',
id: 'testerPanel',
title: 'oldTilte',
//other code
});
```

I have a controller of a different view where I wish to update the panel title:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('testerPanel');
grid.setTitle('newTitle'); //doesn't update the title

//tried with including ref or view in the controller
this.getTestPanel().setTitle('newTitle'); //this didn't update it either
```

How can I update the panel title? Also for both above tries, if I print the `console.info(grid)` or `console.info(this.getTestPanel())`, I always see the updated title in the console output but the UI itself remains unchanged

Comment: Are sure there are no other instances of the grid? You use getCmp to get the instance of the grid and that is always risky because you must make sure the IDs are unique. Use ComponentQuery instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below Jsfiddle Demo for your requirement its is working.I  have made the Grid with initial having title. Grid toolbar contains one button '**Change Title**' click to see your required solution.

`this.up('grid').setTitle('New Grid Title');`

Here is the working Demo for Above : http://jsfiddle.net/PhAbR/83/